# Java code not running

Tags: java, cmd

I had asked a question regarding this 2 days back, and didn't receive an answer that worked. So I'm asking this again in a far more detailed manner.
Problem is, I can't run java codes via command prompt. I have the environment variables set.

The result of `java -version` and `javac -version` :

```
E:\AG's Stuff\Coding\Java>java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

E:\AG's Stuff\Coding\Java>javac -version
javac 1.7.0_25
```

All tutorials out there say to do this:

```
C : > javac MyFirstJavaProgram.java
C : > java MyFirstJavaProgram 
Hello World
```

My program is called Test.java . The contents of the program is:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        for(int a=0;a<=10;a++)
        {
            System.out.print(a+"\n");
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run it, this happens:

```
E:\AG's Stuff\Coding\Java>javac test.java

E:\AG's Stuff\Coding\Java>java test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test (wrong name: Tes
t)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

The previous question had some replies relating to packages, but I'm wondering why such an absolutely simple piece of code would require packages and stuff..

This code also worked perfectly on an online code runner, so I'm assuming the problem is not an error in the code itself.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Try

```
java Test  // Capital T not small t in test
```

because your class Name is `Test` not `test`

Also Save the file as `Test.java` instead of `test.java` , Since your class name is public , So `file name` should be same as `class Name`

**Note :** Please don't wonder anything , just read out the exception , it is loud and clear !!

Comment: Okay that worked.... I was typing `java test` instead of `java Test` all this time. So much for answers telling me to use packages and whatnot. Thanks!